# Can i rewrite a wireless beacon frame?

Tags: frame, network-protocols, wifi, wireless

My question is, can i add an extra parameter to broadcast in a beacon frame ? This parameter needs to be read by devices to get an additional and helpful information about the access point. Sorry that i can't say what parameter it is, i just had this brilliant idea which i think no one has thought of.  So please tell me if there is a way to change the protocol stack /tweak the frame for that particular access point. If i can't do this with a beacon frame, how may i be able to send free signals that unauthenticated devices could receive ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, and some manufactures actually already doing this for example to indicate how busy their access points are. But of course, because it is not part of the 802.11 standard all other devices will just ignore this TLV(Type Length Value) value or interpret it differently from the beacon frame. If you want to add a new parameter to the beacon, then you will probably need to modify MAC (Media Access Control) firmware for a Wi-Fi chip. Unfortunately in majority of cases the firmware is supplied as a binary because manufacture don't want to reveal any details of their SoC design. I am not sure, may be there is an open MAC firmware with driver available - google it :)

Comment: Andrew thank you very much for this reply ! I really do appreciate, you put things in perspective. Now i think i know what to look for. Thank you.